# Can you allow users to select a specific timezone on a date / time field?

Tags: datetime, timezone

We have a scenario where we want to allow a user (who works in EST) to be able to select a date / time for a specific timezone. Our users submit orders for customers across multiple time zones and are used to working in the customer's local time zone.  We want a field that allows the user to select the date, time, and a dropdown for them to choose the timezone.

Is this possible?

I know everything gets stored in GMT, but I want the user to be able to select 11/1/22 2:00pm CST, and then that would show appropriately based on each user's personally selected time zone.

The bonus question: is it possible to limit that drop down to a specific set of timezones (not all the variations that SF allows in your profile)?

Comment: welcome to SFSE!  Please see [ask] on getting the most from the Community;  Sure - it is possible - what have you tried?

Comment: Have you looked into the [Time data type](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.custom_field_time_overview.htm&type=5)?

Comment: We are currently using the Time data type. However, this causes an issue in reports as all other dates / times show in my selected time zone. The "Time data" field stays as what was selected and there is no option for time zone selection as time zone's need to be tied to a date.